# WooCommerce REST API Get customer by phone number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

How to find a customer by phone number [billing_phone] with WooCommerce REST API ?

I know the phone number is registered in 'wp_usermeta', but I do not know how to search on it.
Someone could give me a piece of code or a solution. Because in the documentation of WooCommerce, there is nothing about it, I use the v3 API woocommerce.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue when retrieving products, or orders that had specific values. Try adding a filter to the api call similar to whats below.

```
$params = ['filter' => [
              'billing_phone' => '8718309829' // Whatever the billing phone value is
              ]
           ];
$customers = $this->woocommerce->get("customers", $params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try in a few hours and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Do you have a complete example with your product research?

Comment: The filter param is no longer valid, use field specific parameters: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#what-happened-to-the-filter-query-parameter